# How to Install TP-Link TL-WN823N V3 driver on Rasperry Pi 1 A+ without internet abilities?

Tags: networking, drivers

My raspberry pi A1 can't connect to the internet without a dongle. However, the dongle I bought (TP-Link TL-WN823N V3) requires the internet to install its' driver.

https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn823n/

I've done my best to read the documentation and search around, but it's rather unclear. Can anyone point me to a single file to download, or a set of commands that don't require the internet?

Comment: Can you tether your phone? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Simple answer no. Thank you for your welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it in about five days...maybe.

Go here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Select your Ubuntu version, i.e. Jammie, Kinetic, etc. in the drop-down box. Search for bc, dkms and build-essential. Be sure to locate their dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies. Once you've download about fifteen or so packages on another computer, transfer them with a USB stick or similar to the desktop of your Ubuntu computer. Open a terminal and install them:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

It may complain that a package is missing a dependency. If so, download that and add it to the desktop and try again.

Write many posts to tell old Chili how you're stuck. Rinse and repeat.

Once that's all done, get this: https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702/archive/refs/heads/main.zip Download it and then transfer it to your desktop, too. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, back to the terminal.

```
cd ~/Desktop/88x2bu-20210702-main
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll see if I can make a script to autmate this, rather then having to download tons of files (which I did once try, and 2 hours later it still didn't work!)